# Javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: when trying to look up the jndi name in JavaEE and Wildfly

Tags: wildfly, jndi, java-ee-7, java-ee-8

I am doing some unit testing using javaee and wildly so I am in the client project trying to lookup the jndi name remotely in order to test a service located of course in the ejb, all is fine and the handshake is done correctly but while testing I am getting an exeception which is:

```
test.ServiceLocatorException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:
/phenomenon-ejb/ClientSessionBean!utilities.CllientSessionBeanRemote
```

Here is a snippet showing the appname, modulename and this is how I am trying to lookup the jndi:

```
java:global/phenomenon-ear/phenomenon-ejb/ClientSessionBean!utilities.CllientSessionBeanRemote
    java:app/phenomenon-ejb/ClientSessionBean!utilities.CllientSessionBeanRemote
    java:module/ClientSessionBean!utilities.CllientSessionBeanRemote
    java:global/phenomenon-ear/phenomenon-ejb/ClientSessionBean!utilities.CllientSessionBeanLoacal
    java:app/phenomenon-ejb/ClientSessionBean!utilities.CllientSessionBeanLoacal
    java:module/ClientSessionBean!utilities.CllientSessionBeanLoacal
```

Client Code:

```
public class JunitTester {

public static final String jndi = "java:global/phenomenon-ear/phenomenon-ejb/ClientSessionBean!utilities.CllientSessionBeanRemote" ;
private static CllientSessionBeanRemote getProxy() {
    return (CllientSessionBeanRemote) ServiceLocator.getInstance().getProxy(jndi);
}


@org.junit.Test
public void Test() throws NamingException {
System.out.println(JunitTester.getProxy().Verify_No_Existence("Multiskan"));}
```

Any advice could help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> with your client code I was able to run on glassfish successfully....
> Below is the code having said that
>
> 1. if you can test again please give me the exact exception.
> 2. Ensure *Client*.jar is in your classpath in my case its gf-client.jar
> 3. server up and running and you than connect the client

```
Junit

package com.au.clients;

import com.au.ejbs.GreetingI;

import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class JunitTester {

    public static final String jndi = "java:global/ejb3_2_ear_exploded/ejb/Greeting";

    private static GreetingI getProxy() throws NamingException {
        return (GreetingI) ServiceLocator.getInstance().getProxy(jndi);
    }


    @org.junit.Test
    public void Test() throws NamingException {
        System.out.println(getProxy().Verify_No_Existence("Multiskan"));
    }
}

Service locator

import com.au.ejbs.GreetingI;

import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class ServiceLocator {

    public static ServiceLocator getInstance()  {
        ServiceLocator serviceLocator = null;
        if(serviceLocator == null) {
            serviceLocator = new ServiceLocator();
        }
       return serviceLocator;
    }

    public static GreetingI getProxy(String jndi) throws NamingException {
        InitialContext context =new InitialContext();
        GreetingI greeting = context.doLookup(jndi);
        return greeting;

    }


}

output
true

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer, I tried your solution but I got the same exception, I added the client code to the question so you can have a look into it.

Comment: Hello thanks, I will do that shortly and get back to u

Comment: yes I found it in application.xml and it is the same:  <module>
    <ejb>phenomenon-ejb.jar</ejb>
  </module>

Comment: Hey Assuming your exception is still:    test.ServiceLocatorException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:
/phenomenon-ejb/ClientSessionBean!utilities.CllientSessionBeanRemote . Can you please check inside your ear phenomenon-ear you have the jar phenomenon-ejb? I am suspecting that could be the problem please check the exact neme of the ejb you could find that in application.xml in my case its  <module id="ejb3.2-EJB">
        <ejb>ejb.jar</ejb>
    </module> do let me know

Comment: Hey I have edited my previous post <stackoverflow suggests :) > with your client code looks good on glassfish...have a look thanks for your responses.